# A word that describes the reading experience

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm writing a short essay about plays and movies. In movies, the audience experiences the literary text in a sensory way. When the audience reads the play, though, they experience it in what way?

Comment: It may be worth thinking about what actually happens when someone reads a book or a play. When I've had conversations about this in the past, everyone I've talked to has said that when they read, it conjures up images in their head; we don't imagine the words on the page, we experience the images that the words create. So in a sense, even when we read a story, we are still experiencing it at a sensory level, it's just a personal, internal, imaginary experience as opposed to an external sensory one. You create the sensory experience yourself while you were reading the words.

Answer (score 1):

There is ['literary'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/literary?s=t)

E.g. "When the audience read the play, though, they experience it in a *literary* way"

> literary - **adjective**
>
> 1 - pertaining to or of the nature of books and writings, especially those classed as literature : *literary history*.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*